# Find number of occurrences

Tags: macros, conditionals

Is it possible to change te outcome of a command depending on how many times it is called? I would like to have a command with 3 possible outcomes.

1. Case 1: Outcome A in case it only occurs once in the document.
2. Case 2: Outcome B for the first time it occurs in a document where it occurs multiple times and outcome C for the subsequent times it occurs in that document.

I would like not to use any arguments just the name of the command.

I know how to make the second case with a nested `\newcommand`. But does anyone know how to differentiate between case 1 and case 2? In other words, how can I make a command/function that has 3 different outcomes depending on how many times it is called?

Comment: I think this is something for a total counter?

Comment: @Andrew In what context do you need this command? For something citation related?

Comment: @samcarter: Yes, I use it for references. I need to reference some names. The first time I need to give the full name and the subsequent times just the abbreviation. So the first time the command outputs "the long reference (hereafter: the abbreviation)", the second time "the abbreviation". However, if the command is just used one, I would like it to just output the full reference instead of the full reference followed by the abbreviation as it would be superfluous.

Comment: @Andrew: You should have really stated that this is about referencing stuff. Now my solution is pretty useless ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: It is for referencing, but for the moment I don't use bib(la)tex. For the moment I am not using it because I don't have the necessary citation style (I cannot find it on line and I don't have time to make now one myself) for the 'real' references (so for the moment I am writing them myself and importing them from a central .csv). It is just for abbreviating names, not for referencing actual sources. It seems easier to stick with plain (La)TeX instead of adding bib(la)tex?

Answer (score 5):

You indicated in your comment, that you want to use this for citations. This makes the answer easy: use `biblatex`!

`biblatex` has all the necessary tests to deal with this situation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citecounter=true, style=authoryear, citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{duck,
  author    = {Duck, Donald},
  usera      = {Ducky},
  title     = {Bla},
  journal   = {Blub},
  year      = 2017
}

@article{mouse,
  author    = {Mouse, Minnie},
  usera      = {Mousy},
  title     = {Bla},
  journal   = {Blub},
  year      = 2017
}

\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifnum\thecitecounter=1
        \usebibmacro{cite}%
    \else%
         \ifciteseen{%
            \printfield{usera}%
         }{%
            \usebibmacro{cite}, in the following abbreviated as \printfield{usera}%
         }%
    \fi%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

    First citation: \cite{duck}

    Unique citation: \cite{mouse}

  Cite again: \cite{duck}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This applies a total document counter and associates it to a normal counter that counts the number of appearences of the `\foo` command with the features of `xassoccnt`.

The total number of appearences is saved at the end of the document and is available in the second run.

For more convenience, I've defined `\fooonce`, `\foofirst` and `\foomorethanoncebutnotfirst` macros for the output of the `\foo` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}


\newcounter{occur}
\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{occur}{numofoccur}

\newcommand{\foosingle}{%
  \textcolor{red}{This is foo and it occurs only once!}%

}
\newcommand{\foofirst}{%
  \textcolor{blue}{This is foo, it appears more than once but this is the first time!}%

}

\newcommand{\foomorethanoncebutnotfirst}{%
  \textcolor{green}{This is foo and it appears multiple time, for example here, but it is not the first one!}

}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \refstepcounter{occur}%
  % Test for the total numbers first
  \ifnum\TotalValue{numofoccur}=1
  \foosingle%
  \else
  % Check for the current number of appearances...
  \ifnum\value{occur}=1 
  \foofirst%
  \else
  \foomorethanoncebutnotfirst%
  \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\foo

And 

\foo 

again.

\end{document}
```

If the second `\foo` is commented out, the output is

[image]

If the second `\foo` is kept inside, the output is

[image]

Comment: I am using datatool, but it seems like it prevents numofoccur from counting. Is there a possibility to prevent datatool from breaking this? Just loading datatool breaks it, I doesn't even need to call it. I call datatool like this:
 \usepackage[separator={;}]{datatool}

 \DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={key,reference}]{bibfile}{bronnen/bronnenlijst.csv}

 \newcommand{\cl}[1]{%
  \DTLfetch{bibfile}{key}{#1}{reference}%
 }

Comment: @Andrew: I've have never used datatool so far and some files like `bronnenlijst.csv` are not accessible to me -- how should I test this?

Comment: that's true, I was just wondering. I will continue searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of the `.aux` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definename}[3]{%
  % #1 = macro name
  % #2 = name
  % #3 = abbreviation
  \newcommand#1{%
    \if\@usedonce{#1}#2\else#2~(#3)\fi
    \write\@auxout{\string\@isusedonce{\string#1}}%
    \gdef#1{%
      #3\write\@auxout{\string\@isusedtwice{\string#1}}%
      \gdef#1{#3}%
    }%
  }%
  \expandafter\newif\csname ifonce\string#1\endcsname
}
\def\@usedonce#1{TT\fi\csname ifonce\string#1\endcsname}
\def\@isusedonce#1{\global\csname once\string#1true\endcsname}
\def\@isusedtwice#1{\global\csname once\string#1false\endcsname}
\makeatother

\definename{\dickens}{Charles Dickens}{CD}
\definename{\adams}{Douglas Adams}{DA}

\begin{document}

Here I mention Dickens the first time: \dickens

Here I mention Dickens the second time: \dickens

Adams is mentioned just once: \adams

\end{document}
```

Note that you have to compile twice for the macros to align.

[image]

The first time `\dickens` appears, it writes about having been used once in the `.aux` file and redefines itself to just issue the abbreviation and to write in the `.aux` files about having been issued at least twice and redefines itself again to just print the abbreviation.

The `\definename` macro also sets up a conditional for each name; this conditional is set to true if an annotation in the `.aux` file says the macro is used at least once; it is set to false if the macro is used at least twice. When the “once” conditional returns true, just the name is printed the first (and unique) time; otherwise the name and abbreviation is printed. The redefinition of the macro follows.