# Beamer citation in footnote

Tags: beamer, citing

**What I want:**
A bibliography printing style in Beamer, which combines [`\footpartcite`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/38244) with `\autocite`. The first instance of citation of an item will be like this:

[image]

All the subsequent instances will not have any description in footnote (but it will link to the first instance):

[image]

**What I have:**
With my *MWE* (see below) I am able to get this for the first instance (notice the `footnotemark`s):

[image]

Any help is welcome.

**Update:**
I also have some `\footnote`s which I want unchanged (see the following image).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
    @online{bad,
        author = {Bad Man},
        year = {1313},
        title = {Bad Title},
        url = {http://badurl.com/},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165016/38244
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    linkcolor=blue,
    %   backref=true
}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/38244
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
    \setunit{\addnbspace}
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
    \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
    \newunit
    \printfield[]{year}}
{\addsemicolon\space}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

%%%\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footpartcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footpartcite}{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{What I found}
    Something\footnote{This is a footnote with index 1}

    First time, \autocite{bad} \footpartcite{bad}   

    Another thing\footnote{This footnote index should be 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Again}
Next time, \autocite{bad} only
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE (2)** One elegant (yet partial) solution is given by `samcarter` (see below). The only thing left is to link the citations to the first footnote.

Comment: On page 2: `\footpartcite{bad}` is missing.

Comment: @Bobyandbob That was intentional.

Comment: Linking one document: ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a quick hack, simply change the definition of the footnotemarks to be empty.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
    @online{bad,
        author = {{Bad Man}},
        year = {1313},
        title = {Bad Title},
        url = {http://badurl.com/},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165016/38244
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    linkcolor=blue,
%   backref=true
}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/38244
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
    \setunit{\addnbspace}
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
    \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
    \newunit
    \printfield[]{year}}
{\addsemicolon\space}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

%%%\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footpartcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footpartcite}{\addsemicolon\space}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{\insertfootnotetext}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{What I found}
    First time, \autocite{bad} \footpartcite{bad}   
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Again}
    Next time, \autocite{bad} only
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And in combination with footnotes (with a little help from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170512/36296):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citecounter=true,citetracker=true]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
    @online{bad,
        author = {{Bad Man}},
        year = {1313},
        title = {Bad Title},
        url = {http://badurl.com/},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165016/38244
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    linkcolor=blue,
%   backref=true
}

\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/38244
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
{%  
    \ifciteseen{}{%
        \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \let\thefootnote\relax%
        \footnotetext{%
            \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
            \setunit{\addnbspace}
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
            \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
            \newunit%
            \printfield[]{year}%
        }%
        \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
    }%
    \autocite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  }
{\addsemicolon\space}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{What I found}
    test\footnote{test}

    First time, \cite{bad}   

    test\footnote{test}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Again}
    Next time, \cite{bad} only
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I also have `\footnote`s. :-(

Comment: @pushpen.paul Please see my second solution.

Comment: It works... only a minor issue remains. The all instances are linked to the first page of the document (I wanted it to link to the first instance) :-)

Comment: Apart from that, is it possible to use only one command that will check the number of instances and do the rest automatically?

Comment: @pushpen.paul no idea about the links, but to make this automatic, you can have a look at the `\ifciteseen` test of biblatex, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358011/36296 for an example.

Comment: I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285710/38244 Can that be used for links? :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164269/link-biblatex-bibliography-to-citations-without-printing-backrefs might be more helpful. I think you have to somehow set the `bibhypertarget` in the footnote - I just cannot find what input you have to feed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64011/discussion-between-pushpen-paul-and-samcarter).

Comment: @pushpen.paul You'll need `\ifciteseen` (as I wrote in my comment) and not `\ifnum\thecitecounter=1`. The later gives you the total number of citations of an entry.

Answer (score 2):

All that seems to be missing is a `\blx@anchor` in the footnotetext. In order to be able to use that `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are required. And I have added another test slide in the beginning to show that it does not link to the first slide anymore. Apart from that it's exactly [samcarter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386708/120953).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citecounter=true,citetracker=true]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
    @online{bad,
        author = {{Bad Man}},
        year = {1313},
        title = {Bad Title},
        url = {http://badurl.com/},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165016/38244
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    linkcolor=blue,
%   backref=true
}

\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/38244
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
{%  
    \ifciteseen{}{%
        \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \let\thefootnote\relax%
        \footnotetext{%
            \blx@anchor
            \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
            \setunit{\addnbspace}
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
            \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
            \newunit%
            \printfield[]{year}%
        }%
        \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
    }%
    \autocite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  }
{\addsemicolon\space}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
    content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{What I found}
    test\footnote{test}

    First time, \cite{bad}   

    test\footnote{test}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Again}
    Next time, \cite{bad} only
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Umm... Having a slight problem when I'm citing inside a `table`. The same cite key is printed in the footnote, although it is printed once already... Should I open a new (follow-up) question?

Comment: @pushpen.paul yes, opening a follow-up question and posting it's link here in the comments would be good. Using the example from my answer and putting the citation inside a `tabular` inside of a `table` I can not recreate your problem.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out the problem is not with `tabular`, but with a previous `algorithm`.